# Why is there a difference between logistic growth output of R and another one?

Tags: r, statistics, nls

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
  var = c(12.69,16.35,20.29,25.08,30.81,38.75,45,49.16,55.15,62.852,68.63,76.64,82.47,85.68,89.14,91.86,95.28,98.17)
)

logisticmodel <- nls(var ~ SSlogis(time, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = df)
summary(logisticmodel)
coef(logisticmodel)
#predict(logisticmodel, data.frame(time = 18))
```

The output given by R is as follows:

```
      phi1       phi2       phi3 
105.737368   7.432555   3.852865
```

But [the website](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/ivytech-collegealgebra/chapter/build-a-logistic-model-from-data/) gives us:

[image]

I know some languages have different outputs. It's normal but I am wondering what your thoughts are?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that different models are being fit.

`nls` with self start function `SSlogis` fits the model (see `help('SSlogis')`)

```
Asym/(1+exp((xmid-input)/scal))
```

or, using your notation,

```
phi1/(1 + exp((phi2 - input)/phi3))
```

Pen and paper shows that the following transformations give the results in the webpage.

```
fit <- nls(var ~ SSlogis(time, phi1, phi2, phi3), data = df)

kappa <- coef(fit)[1]
alpha <- exp(coef(fit)[2]/coef(fit)[3])
beta <- 1/coef(fit)[3]
c(kappa = unname(kappa), alpha = unname(alpha), beta = unname(beta))
#      kappa       alpha        beta 
#105.7373679   6.8832991   0.2595471
```

So, in order to automate this, write a simple function.

```
transf <- function(x){
  kappa <- coef(x)[1]
  alpha <- exp(coef(x)[2]/coef(x)[3])
  beta <- 1/coef(x)[3]
  c(kappa = unname(kappa), alpha = unname(alpha), beta = unname(beta))
}

transf(fit)
```

Comment: Thank you. Why do we use this even though the formula is different? So, as I know the formula is y = c / (1 + a*(e^-b*x)).

Comment: @nerdakgul Like I say in the post, `SSlogis` fits a different model, it fits the formula `Asym/(1 + exp((xmid - x)/scal))`. This is equal to `Asym/(1 + exp(xmid/scal)*exp(-1/scal * x))`. Then, `c = Asym` , `a = exp(xmid/scal)` and `b = 1/scal`. `Asym = coef[1]`, `xmid = coef[2]` and `scal = coef[3]`. And you have the transformations in function `transf`.